# permission denied (publickey) but key seems is present

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, mac

I hope I didn't overlook an answer but so far it seems I'm hitting a brickwall. I'm using VirtualBox on my Mac OS X with an Ubuntu 12.04 guest system. While it works perfectly fine with password authentication, it doesn't work with keys. I just can't seem to find my mistake.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

I'm receiving the following:

```
myhost:~ myusername$ ssh -vp 3022 sshuser@192.168.56.1
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.1 [192.168.56.1] port 3022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ed:7e:bb:97:27:dd:82:82:b7:52:f0:e6:de:0d:f3:0e
debug1: Host '[192.168.56.1]:3022' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: vmssh
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've done the following so far:

```
0 post os install
$ adduser sshuser

1 backup config (remote host)
$ sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.backup
$ sudo chmod a-w /etc/ssh/sshd_config.backup

2. config (remote host)
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

  Port 22
  PermitRootLogin no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowUsers sshuser
  LogLevel Verbose (/var/log/auth.log)

$ mkdir ~/.ssh

3. Generate and send keys (localhost)
if no .ssh dir:
     $ mkdir ~/.ssh
     $ chmod 700 ~/.ssh

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
$ ssh-add id_rsa

$ scp -P 3022 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sshuser@localhost:/home/sshuser/.ssh/uploaded_key.pub

(remote host)
$ touch authorized_files
$ cat uploaded_key.pub >> authorized_files
$ chmod 600 authorized_files
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
$ PasswordAuthentication no

$ sudo service ssh restart

(localhost) 
$ ssh -p 3022 user@host
 (where host = vboxeth ip 192.x.x.x)
```

Comment: You're trying to ssh to `sshuser@192.168.56.1`, but copying your key to `sshuser@localhost`. Derp.

Comment: Not to mention the filename is wrong. Why don't you just use `ssh-copy-id` anyway?

Comment: there may be a number of mistakes there but it should be authorized_keys not authorized_files

Comment: Thank you all for your help guys. Barlop's answer solved the problem. It was a long day... Would you give me that as an answer please, then I can vote for it? :)

EEAA, thanks, the IPs got jumbled bc I was playing around with different adapters. Didn't matter, I use NAT and portforwarding.
@MichaelHampton What did you mean by "the filename is wrong", please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `-i` parameter with the private key path? Like:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host.com
```

Also, check that the private key permissions are restricted only to your user (`chmod 700` for example).

Comment: `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa` The client offered the key to the server, so the client must have thought the key was okay.

Comment: You are accessing the server on port 3022 but in the sshd_config you have setup por 22.